# bring to back doesnt work in c++ builder bcb6

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-6, tframe, tpanel

I have a `TFrame` with some components on it, and among all it I have a `TPanel` and a `TPaintBox` such that the PaintBox size is the same as the Panel.

I would like that user will see the Panel and not only the PaintBox.

The problem is that when I right click on the Panel and choose `Control->Send to Back`, it doesn't work.

Any assumption, or suggestion for solution?

*I am working with Borland C++Builder 6.

Answer (score 0):

`TPaintBox` is a `TGraphicControl` descendant.  It has no `HWND` of its own, it simply draws on its `Parent` when the `Parent` is painted.  As such, a `TPanel` (which has an `HWND` of its own) can never appear behind a `TPaintBox` unless the `TPaintBox` is a child of the `TPanel`.